# Increasing server storage space

Tags: windows-server-2003

I need to increase the server storage space. Does anyone know how to do this please? This is a windows 2003 terminal server and MY OB and other third party softwares are installed into this server with 120 GB storage space. Now only 1 GB free space is left and the normal file operation is not allowed due to this small free space. I have uninstalled the unwanted applications and user profiles, but still we get only additional 500 MB free space. Any help would be much appreciated. We don't prefer to touch the older applications data such as MY OB files.Thanks.

Comment: You need to get another hard drive or migrate the services off that server.  This question is not very good and if you could elaborate more on your environment in might help.  Although we will never be able to tell you what files you should delete.

Comment: Are you looking for help on adding additional physical drives? Or help on finding what's using up your space right now so you can delete it or clean it up? Or help on changing the configuration so space that's currently used for some other purpose is available for storage? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2003? If it's been in service a while, you can probably delete the uninstall folders for the hundreds of updates and service packs under c:\Windows. They're hidden and listed by KB ID.

Aside from that, you either need to migrate to a new server or add another drive to store user profiles and other data. A Windows 2003 system drive can theoretically be expanded, given RAID controller support and 3rd party utilities, but I do not recommend it.

Edit: I also recommend taking a look at [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), though there are other similar programs with the same result. It's great for finding what is using your space and visualizing it.

Comment: Thanks guys for all replies. I am looking for adding an additional drive because its bit risky to uninstall the older service packs or system data so that the applications installed in the C drive( only drive in the server) can utilize the extra free space from the additional drive. Thank You.

Comment: Note: I didn't say uninstall the service packs, I said delete the uninstall files. Windows Server 2003 keeps a copy of all old files that it updates when it installs patches. These can grow quite large, since they can sometimes be as large as each update installed.

Answer (score 0):

When forced by the limits of an old 2003 server, I've removed those KB directories dozens of times without a single issue (when I had no other short-term options). When was the last time you needed to uninstall a service pack or 2-year old windows update anyway?  To me the other option is [P2V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415). That's easier then upgrading the drive. But if you're concerned about some abnormal behavior of deleting those uninstall files, don't be :).  It's better then a down server.

If another drive seems to be your only long-term option (cough P2V cough) then you can move the pagefile to get some space back quickly.  You can also easily move the printer spool if it's a print server (default to c:\windows\system32\spool\printers).

Files that are not needed for a server to function properly (OK to delete in a pinch):

- C:\windows\$NTuninstallKB*
- C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download (these are downloaded windows updates so don't delete the Download folder itself, just the big folders underneath it, if any)
- C:\windows\Temp
- C:\windows\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1 (logs used by IIS, if never cleaned up they'll be a ton in there.  If you can't delete due to tracking requirements you can compress the folder to get most of the space back)

As @Hyppy says, space analysis is  your friend.  My favorite is the free [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/).

Comment: The problem with this server is that its slowly dying. We cannot install a new software into the server to do the space analysis. I have checked the above folders, but the space freed will not be more than 1 GB. Thanks for the idea of p2v. I am going to check this out.

Comment: Disk2vhd has been a great tool for me to get old servers on 2003 to running in Hyper-V.  Make sure you check the "fix up hal for virtual pc" before creating (for 2003 and XP machines).  Also stop all services with open data like SQL, Exchange, etc first.  You can point the .vhd creation to a network drive to prevent filling up local drive.  Once finished shutdown local physical server. !! But don't do anything to the physical box until you are certain the .vhd comes up in virtual w/o issues.  I've had to try a 2nd time every so often.